# Hide or Removing keyboard button on CardIO Scann screen (Android)

Tags: android, input, keyboard, cardio

In my scann screen, keyboard button shown on the right bottom. I don't want to enter card information manuelly, so i want to hide or remone this button on my screen. 
In my Util class which i used codes below

> ```
>     scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_APP_TOKEN, CARD_IO_APP_TOKEN);
>     // customize these values to suit your needs.
>     scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_EXPIRY, false); 
>     scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_CONFIRMATION, true); 
>     scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CVV, false); 
>     scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY, false);
>     scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_POSTAL_CODE, false);
>     // MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE is arbitrary and is only used within this activity.
>     context.startActivityForResult(scanIntent, CARD_IO_REQUEST_CODE);
> ```

Any other solution?

**UPDATE**

I solved my problem. Only i changed this two line:

> scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CVV, true);
>   scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY, true);

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 7):

Change this attribute EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY to true in order to hide the keyboard entry

```
            scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY, true); // default: false
```